# TypeError: $(".slide-out-div").tabSlideOut is not a function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I was basically trying to follow http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html tutorial and I'm having that error, what is the problem?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>
```

> ```
> <style type="text/css" media="screen">  
>     .slide-out-div {
>      padding: 20px;
>      width: 250px;
>      background: #f2f2f2;
>      border: #29216d 2px solid;
>      }
>      </style>
> ```

```
            <script>
         $(function(){
             $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
                 tabHandle: '.handle',                              //class of the element that will be your tab
                 pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif',          //path to the image for the tab (optionaly can be set using css)
                 imageHeight: '122px',                               //height of tab image
                 imageWidth: '40px',                               //width of tab image    
                 tabLocation: 'left',                               //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
                 speed: 300,                                        //speed of animation
                 action: 'click',                                   //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
                 topPos: '200px',                                   //position from the top
                 fixedPosition: false                               //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
             });
         });



         </script>
        <div class="slide-out-div">
        <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users.html">Content</a>
        <h3>Contact me</h3>
        <p>Thanks for checking out my jQuery plugin, I hope you find this useful.
        </p>
        <p>This can be a form to submit feedback, or contact info</p>
    </div>
```

> [04:54:57.945] TypeError: $(".slide-out-div").tabSlideOut is not a
>   function @

Comment: Yes he did (it's the second `script` tag)

Comment: Are you sure the plugin script was loaded without any errors?

Comment: @bergi yes there are no errors

Comment: I get the following error in Chrome console: `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-c: "http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js".` Try downloading the javascriptfile and run it locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a debugger in your browser, most modern ones do so press F12 to check it, then you can see if all the scripts get loaded correctly and with the `typeof` function you can check what tabSlideOut is (undefined or function).

I think you copy pasted it from here: http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html. Can you double check if you copied everything, including css, correctly?

Comment: You are correct sir, I had multiple instances of Jquery loaded guess that prevented it from working

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
jQuery(function() {

});
```

instead of $

Comment: that does not fix it unfortunately

Comment: try to use <script type="text/javascript"> instead of <script>. I have already use this plugin and I don't have this problem